# Watch/monitor background job for certain keyword

Tags: node.js, bash

In a bash script, I'd like to watch/monitor a background process/job in the following way:

- Run a command (in my case, nodeJS) in the background
- Monitor its output, but do not display it
- As soon as the output contains the word "Error" or the job exits/stops:

  - display the last output (i.e. the full error message)
  - exit the script

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

### You can do it with [`strace`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/strace.1.html):

In the simplest case `strace` runs the specified command until it  exits.
       It  intercepts  and  records  the  system  calls  which are called by a
       process and the signals which are received by a process.  The  name  of
       each  system  call,  its  arguments and its return value are printed on
       standard error or to the file specified with the `-o` option.

Such as:

```
strace -o /path/to/file.txt process_to_monitor
```

Then you can use [`tail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tail.1posix.html) to extract the last part of the file (the last 10 lines by default).

```
tail /path/to/file.txt -n100
```

In case you want to copy the last 100 hundred lines.

And then you `grep` whichever string you want from it.